# Transaction isolation and reading from multiple tables on SQL Server Express and SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

I have a database with a main table (lets call it Owner) and several sub tables with holdings (like Cars, Books etc).

For example:

- `Owner` has columns: `owner_id, name`
- `Cars` has columns: `owner_id (foreign key), brand`
- `Books` has columns: `owner_id (foreign key), title, author`

My program should calculate statistics like *How many BMW owners also owns a Harry Potter book* using various third party libraries. I want to read all rows from all tables at the same time and then do the analysis in non-sql code.

I want to read all tables using separate `Select * From X` statements. I cannot use one big join since it would return too many rows ((owners * cars * books) instead of (owners + cars + books)). A Union doesn't cut it either since the tables contain different columns of different types.

I have set

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

but I'm having some issues anyway.

If I stress the database by running two threads, one randomly inserting or deleting and the other reading I sometimes get inconsistent results, like `Cars` have been deleted between reading `Owners` and reading the `Cars` table.

I have a few questions:

1. What's the proper way of preventing modification when reading from multiple tables one by one? No table must be modified until all have been read.

   I'm using SQL Server 2005 (on network) and SQL Server 2005 Express (local). Can I explicitly get locks on multiple tables at the same time?
2. If I run against my local SQL Server Express database, I can't make it work no matter what I do. If I run against my networked SQL server 2005 database, I can make it work (with some effort). Does SQL Server Express support transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE? I believe it should. The differences could be due to a slow network connection but I don't know.

   On my local db, I can not prevent modification in between reads. That is, one thread is randomly deleting a random owner (first cars, then books, then owner) or inserting a new owner (insert owner, insert 2 cars, insert 2 books). Another thread is reading using:

   ```
   Begin Tran
   Select owner_id From Owner
   Select owner_id, brand From Cars
   Select owner_id, title, author From Books
   Commit Tran
   ```

   No matter what I do, sometimes I get an owner with zero cars or zero books. This should never happen since all inserts and deletes are in a single transaction. I seems like the express server doesn't lock Owner, Cars and Books statements at the same time.

   On the networked SQL Server 2005, it works fine but it could be because of a slow connection and thus lower probability of simultaneous execution.
3. On my local db, I am starting every transaction with a dummy `Select` from all tables to prevent deadlocking. I don't understand why this prevents deadlocking but not modification of the tables. This is not necessary on the networked SQL Server 2005.

At the moment, I can't tell if I've misunderstood something about transaction isolation or if it's an issue with differences between SQL Server Express and SQL Server 2005. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice of loading all data in one go means very few options:

- Use sp_getapplock to serialise access through the relevant code
- Use TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK on the reads in a transaction

You have issues because `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` only affects *isolation* of the locks: you need to control *duration* (`HOLDLOCK`) and *granularity* + *mode* (`TABLOCKX`)

Comment: Thanks, sp_getapplock seems like it could help.

Comment: I used the sp_getapplock option since it was the easiest to implement. It will not protect me if other applications modify the DB but that's not an issue for the moment. Thanks for explaining how transaction isolation works.

Answer (score -1):

> I sometimes get inconsistent results,

Unless you will later on do batch processing on a database that is otherwise not used, better get used to certain fluctuations which WILL NOT MATTER ANYWAY.

Unless you have very few entries the changes wont matter in absolute numbers. You deal with statistics anyway. Use READ COMMITED and deal with the inconsitencies by accepting that the data set is not static.

Anything else will totally kill perforamnce.

OR go batch processing.

Alternatively: use a SNAPSHOT to seal a "view in time" of the database.

Comment: Actually, it does matter. Certain combinations (like an owner with no cars) should never happen and will be treated as errors. It doesn't matter if the data changes as long as my snapshot is internally consistent.

Comment: Acutally it does not matter. Statistical inconsistencies are part of working with statistics anway. When you deal with 300.000 data points - how important are 2 bad ones? Not at all.

Comment: Some combinations should never happen. Ever. If they do, we have a huge problem. Getting false positives is not acceptable but missing a possible error would be even worse. So, it does matter.