# Time when PostgreSQL ISOLATION LEVEL takes effect seems to be after first SELECT

Tags: postgresql, mvcc

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.5.3.

I am trying to understand why I see a difference in behavior between the two routines below.  I find this behavior counter-intuitive, but there may be a very good reason for it; I just want to know what it is if so.

Setting `ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ` does not seem to take effect until after the first `SELECT` statement.

The only difference between the two routines is that in "Routine 2" I put in a superfluous `SELECT 1 ;` statement, whereas in "Routine 1" I did not do this.  I got my desired results in "Routine 2".

See [my (overly-lengthy) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319573/transaction-isolation-across-multiple-tables-using-postgresql-mvcc) that I posted earlier in which I incorrectly assumed the behavior I was seeing was something to do with what particular tables I was querying.

I've modified the routine from [krokodilko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/krokodilko)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42321817/7484561) to demonstrate what I'm seeing.  Thanks, krokodilko!

---

These are meant to be executed serially, in the order listed, switching back and forth between two separate sessions.

### Routine 1

Session 1:

```
testdb=# CREATE TABLE t1( x int ) ;
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1),(2),(3) ;
INSERT 0 3
```

Session 2:

```
testdb=# START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ ;
START TRANSACTION
```

Session 1:

```
testdb=# DELETE FROM t1 WHERE x = 2 ;
DELETE 1
```

Session 2:

```
testdb=# SELECT * FROM t1 ;
 x 
---
 1
 3
(2 rows)
```

(why am I seeing the effects from session 1 here?)

Session 2:

```
testdb=# COMMIT ;
COMMIT
```

---

Session 1:

```
testdb=# CREATE TABLE t1( x int ) ;
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1),(2),(3) ;
INSERT 0 3
```

Session 2:

```
testdb=# START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ ;
START TRANSACTION
testdb=# SELECT 1 ;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

(why should I have to do this?)

Session 1:

```
testdb=# DELETE FROM t1 WHERE x = 2 ;
DELETE 1
```

Session 2:

```
testdb=# SELECT * FROM t1 ;
 x 
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

(that's what I expected to see!)

Session 2:

```
testdb=# COMMIT ;
COMMIT
testdb=# SELECT * FROM t1 ;
 x 
---
 1
 3
(2 rows)
```

(that's also what I expected to see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html) (emphasis mine):

> REPEATABLE READ
>
> All statements of the current transaction can only see rows committed **before the first query** or data-modification statement was executed in this transaction.

I can only guess the motivation for making it this way, but I think it's because it simply doesn't matter until you start querying for data. Once you start to query the data is consistent.

Comment: Fair enough!  Thanks!  Any idea why this is?

Comment: The motivation comes from the SQL standard. This is how repeatable read is defined